# google map not working in release, android

Tags: android, google-maps, testing, google-api

I have a question about my google map, It's working on simulators and when I'm loading app on my phone using USB, but it doesn't work after uploading it on alfa-test. It's showing me empty map

Comment: KEY CASE  .Read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Answer (score 0):

Generate SH1 key from release key store and update sh1 in google console.